# Having Excel properly increment a formula

Tags: excel

I have a set of data and I am using a formula compositing of INDEX and MATCH to find the value of in another sheet. The formula works in getting the data but the autofill isn't working how I want it to. There are tons of cell references in the formula but I only want to increment one of them. Giving several examples isn't helping the autofill guess the pattern.

```
=INDEX(CellData!A1:CellData!LN2, 2,MATCH(Data!B1&Data!A2,CellData!A1:CellData!LN1,0))
```

This is the range for the index

```
CellData!A1:CellData!LN2
```

I am grabbing the 2nd row value of that range

```
, 2,
```

I am concatenating the values of Data's B1 and A2 to form a search keyword. It combines to form a word (ex CVProfileFinal (Data B1) + 1 (Data A2))This is where I need help. When using autofill I only want to increment the 2nd A2 to A3, A4, etc. and keep all the other references constant. I can only assume the best way to do this is through macros, however I have no experience with them. Any help is appreciated.

```
MATCH(Data!B1&Data!A2,CellData!A1:CellData!LN1,0))
```

Comment: Take a look at [relative, absolute, and mixed references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9)

Comment: @BigBen This worked flawlessly, thanks so much.